# Как правильно отрисовать тайлы в юнити? Помогите правильно отрисовать тайлы

Tags: unity3d, render, tile, tilemap

Имеется одна Tilemap и палитра с двумя порезанными изометрическими спрайт-щитами. При попытке нарисовать структуру из тайлов, возникает проблема последовательности отрисовки, точнее проблема со слоями скорее. Тайл одного спрайт-щита рисуется поверх тайла другого спрайт-щита, но если поменять их местами, то всё нормально. Сколько бы не пробовал менять настройки Tilemap, ничего не меняется, разве что становится хуже, что и так понятно. Помогите разобраться и выявить причину ошибки.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TileMap` не пользовался, но думаю что его смысл отрисовать всё за минимальное количество вызовов отрисовки кадра (`DrawCall`) для производительности. Чем меньше отрисовок, тем быстрее кадр готов.

Все спрайты одного атласа (`SpriteSheet`) отрисовываются за одну отрисовку в чём и есть смысл соединения спрайтов в атлас. В обычной ситуации, если между несколькими спрайтами из одного аталса (`A`) находится спрайт из другова (`B`), то они отрисовываются по очерёдно, то-есть 3 отрисовки (`A`, `B`, `A`).

2 атласа в `TileMap`, отрисовываются за 2 вызова в порядке установленной очереди, отсюда и визуальные дифекты перекрытия.

Просто создай новый атлас содержащий эти 2.